# vector reflexivity under setoid equality using CoRN MathClasses

Tags: equality, typeclass, coq

I have a simple lemma:

```
Lemma map2_comm: forall A (f:A->A->B) n (a b:t A n), 
                   (forall x y, (f x y) = (f y x)) -> map2 f a b = map2 f b a.
```

which I was able to prove using standard equality (≡). Now I am need to prove the similar lemma using setoid equality (using CoRN MathClasses). I am new to this library and type classes in general and having difficulty doing so. My first attempt is:

```
Lemma map2_setoid_comm  `{Equiv B} `{Equiv (t B n)} `{Commutative B A}:
  forall (a b: t A n),
    map2 f a b = map2 f b a.
Proof.
  intros.
  induction n.
  dep_destruct a.
  dep_destruct b.
  simpl.
```

(here '=' is 'equiv'). After 'simpl' the goal is "(nil B)=(nil B)" or "[]=[]" using VectorNotations. Normally I would finish it using 'reflexivity' tactics but it gives me:

```
Tactic failure: The relation equiv is not a declared reflexive relation. Maybe you need to require the Setoid library.
```

I guess I need somehow to define reflexivity for vector types, but I am not sure how to do that. Please advise.

Comment: Somehow related discussion here: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.science.mathematics.logic.coq.club/3716

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all the lemma definition needs to be adjusted to:

```
Lemma map2_setoid_comm : forall `{CO:Commutative B A f} `{SB: !Setoid B}  ,
                  forall n:nat, Commutative (map2 f (n:=n)).
```

To be able to use *reflexivity*:

```
Definition vec_equiv `{Equiv A} {n}: relation (vector A n) := Vforall2 (n:=n) equiv.
Instance vec_Equiv `{Equiv A} {n}: Equiv (vector A n) := vec_equiv.
```